# Converting multiple VFP9 classes to C#

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

Let me start by saying that I have not programmed in a heavily OO programming language since Java in college (I graduated in December 2005). Since I've graduated I have been programming with FoxPro 2.5 - VFP9. Now, the company I work for is pushing to convert all of our FoxPro applications to C#.

My part of this project is converting our report parsing application. In VFP9 it consists of 5-6 forms (none of which will be carried over as we have created a new C# front-end to replace it), a single **Base** class that contains all of our standard methods, and approximately 575 individual **parser** classes (some of which do nothing but set a few parser specific variables/properties and call the needed base classes). Some of the parsers contain their own custom methods which still use and interact with the base methods and global properties.

Now for my question...

From a design standpoint, we would like for our new C# front-end to spawn multiple executables (3-5 EXEs) that will call our new C# base/parser class libraries (DLLs). My original thought was that I would have one solution/project with a Base_Code.cs and the other 575 parser.cs files (H1.cs, H2.cs, H3.cs, etc). However, we need the capability to build each .cs file independently of the others as I may be updating the Base_Code.cs while my co-worker is updating the H1.cs.

How do I best structure this? Do I keep one solution but create 576 projects or do I create 576 solutions all using the same Namespace as another team is attempting currently?

There are several global variables/properties that we use throughout the base code and each parser (these will be passed in from the front-end application) like file paths, file names, etc. that will be static so this needs to be taken into consideration as well when thinking of the design.

EDIT FOR EXAMPLE ******

The C# front-end is basically a queueing system and file/status viewer. This front-end "queues" the reports we pick up throughout the day. The report at the top of the list determines what DLL will be needed. The front-end application and the DLLs are completely separate.

Example: H00001_2342318.MSG - this will call the H00001 DLL
         H00002_3422551.MSG - this will call the H00002 DLL

Each H00001, H00002, etc (575 DLLs in total) will use methods that are in the BASE DLL.

If I have to update the H00001 DLL, I need to do so without having to rebuild all 575 DLLs.

Comment: `"we need the capability to build each .cs file independently of the others as I may be updating the Base_Code.cs while my co-worker is updating the H1.cs"` - I'm not sure I follow that line of reasoning. I don't see any reason why team members can't modify files as needed from source control (even the same file). When it's time for a new build, re-build from what's in source control. Why is it necessary for each file to be its own assembly?

Comment: 576 projects and 576 assemblies each with one class is a **ton** of overhead for maintenance, etc. like @David says, to me it sounds like 1 solution 1 project 1 assembly and proper use of source control.

Comment: @David I personally have never used source control but I understand its purpose and I agree that this would probably be the best route to take. However, we do not have any source control in place (though we have requested it and I believe other departments are using TFS or SourceSafe). Unfortunately, this company is as slow as Congress for getting anything so it's not guarunteed that we will have it anytime soon.

Comment: @Spoon82: Even without source control, I still don't see a reason to put every class into its own compiled assembly. If the root of the problem is a lack of source control, the solution is to use source control. The solution is *not* to obscure the code to the point that you've convinced yourself you don't need source control. That doesn't solve a problem, it just creates another problem. Honestly, without knowing more about the application, I'm not seeing any compelling reason why all of the code shouldn't be in a single project. Or at most an application project and a business logic project.

Comment: @David - Let me try to explain a little more clearly why we want each file to be built separately. As it stands now with our VFP application, we have a process that runs daily and updates our parsing application with any new/updated classes (base or individual parser). It's basically copying the file from our source network to our production network. We want to keep all of that the same. So I guess I need to know if I rebuild a project that has 575 files but only 1 of those has been modified, will all 575 files now have todays date as the last modified date?

Comment: @Spoon82: The compiled output isn't the code, it's the DLL. This process of updating the production code sounds unnecessarily complex. (Again, there could be details with which we're unfamiliar outside of your team.) If there's an update to be pushed to production, why not just deploy the whole updated application to production? The source code files themselves shouldn't be on production, just the compiled output. Maybe the process you're describing makes sense for a FoxPro system, but it doesn't sound like it makes a lot of sense for a .NET application.

Comment: @David - Basically I need each FoxPro class I currently have to be its own DLL. The 575 parser DLLs need to inherit from the base DLL. All of these DLLs need to be modified/built separately from one another so each can be moved to production on its own. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @Spoon82: It doesn't make sense, no. However, in order to accomplish that then each one will need to be its own project. As John mentioned in his comment earlier, this is a lot of overhead. You can put them all into one solution, or break them out into multiple solutions, or both really. The same project can exist in more than one solution.

Comment: @David - It's definitely a lot of overhead. I prefer one solution with multiple projects myself though I wish I didn't even need to do that much. I'm just concerned with VS performance when trying to open the solution with 575 projects! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Spoon82: That may end up being the only reason to use separate solutions. Though if each one is small enough it might not be an issue. What I truly don't envy is whoever needs to write and maintain the build/deploy process for that. That's where all of the overhead and multiple points of failure are going to be significant.

Comment: @David - For the most part, the build/deploy is all manual. If I have to update H1.cs, I would rebuild it and copy the updated DLL to a central location. Our automated process would scan that location for any updated files and copy over any it finds to production. Luckily we don't have to update these files very often.

Comment: Developing software without source control makes me scratch my head.  Especially with the usage of the word "We".  Manually merging code on a network share is such a universally bad idea that it's one of the few things that I can categorically call "wrong".

Comment: @RQDQ - Like I said, that's out of our control (pardon the pun). We have requested it and we hope it'll be setup soon. However, it does not really provide me the option of building each DLL separately.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a "plugin" kind of architecture. This lets you drop in / update dlls (assemblies) without recompiling the main app.

E.g. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62

and related.

Comment: I believe our front-end application will be using the plugin architecture. My part of this project is the actual DLLs themselves.

Answer (score 0):

576 projects and/or solutions is a maintenance nightmare. I have far fewer (75 or so) projects across less than a dozen solutions for an entire suite of products. This includes tests, framework components, etc. and the only way I keep on top of it is via strict naming/path conventions, source control, and scripts for automation.

Speaking of tests, you should be planning for unit tests (greenfield development presents an excellent opportunity for this; don't miss the opportunity). Tests go in a separate project; this is another reason why each class shouldn't be given its own assembly. You could theoretically double your project count.

I would start with a single solution with logically separated projects (e.g. break things out by function/dependency, and add a test project for each library).

Source control eliminates any concerns about conflicts between team members. If you have internal challenges getting source control up and running, look into Team Foundation Services Online: http://tfs.visualstudio.com/. Setup is incredibly easy and it's free for up to 5 users.

If you do end up needing greater disconnection between projects, you may want to consider using NuGet packages with a [local repository](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) to isolate/version different, discrete components. This wouldn't be my first step, but it is a worthwhile option to keep in mind.

From the comments, it sounds like you are currently performing daily deployments of autonomous units.

1. This seems risky. Can this be driven by configuration/data rather than code changes?
2. 576 completely autonomous units seems like a problem with application design (e.g. reuse?)
3. Assuming that new code must be deployed every day, perhaps a scripting language + DLR could make this easier. Dynamic compilation of c# is also a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Each parser is separate because it has its own variables to set and may have its own reports to parse. Basically, we are a medical billing software company. My team takes reports that we receive from payers (575 of them currently: example - Blue Cross/Blue Shield of AL) and we have to split those reports up and parse them back to each individual site (example - USA Medical Center). Every payer may have its own reports to parse so we have to code that report custom to that parser. We try to put as much reusable code into our single base parser as we can!

Comment: That makes sense. Depending on the size of these individual parsers, dynamic compilation might help you. I have an application where c# snippets are stored in a database (configurable from a UI) and compiled/cached at runtime. This is very flexible, but works best with smaller (<100 lines) of code.

Comment: Another thought: if you do create a separate assembly for each payer, don't put them in a single solution. VS and various plugins perform solution-wide operations, and if there is no relationship between each parser, you will probably experience a significant slowdown for no benefit. Perhaps a solution for each letter of the alphabet.

Comment: I've updated my original post with examples. I need to point out that the application that will use the DLLs is a completely separate solution/project. My team will be maintaining the DLLs so I don't think dynamic compilation will help my side of things.